# Why does secondary subdomain for Discourse in AWS fail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, discourse

I have a domain for a public-facing static website that loads fine whether it’s entered into the browser as `example.com`, `http://example.com`, or `https://example.com`.

I have a private (accessible by login) subdomain for a Discourse forum that loads fine whether it’s entered into the browser as `discourse.example.com`, `http://discourse.example.com`, or `https://discourse.example.com`.

The subdomain for Discourse is achieved by addition of a record to the AWS Route 53 hosted zone:

> Record name: discourse.example.com
>
> Record type: A
>
> Value: 123.45.678.90
>
> Alias: No
>
> TTL: 300
>
> Routing policy: Simple

I’d like to provide a shorter alternative/secondary subdomain for Discourse. So I added another record, nearly same as the prior, only with the record name changed from `discourse.example.com` to `d.example.com`.

Strangely, this works in HTTP, but in HTTPS the browser warns:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from d.example.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>
> Learn more
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

What am I missing? Should I be going about this a different way?

My AWS Certificate covers `example.com` and `*.example.com`. My CloudFront distribution covers `example.com` and `d.example.com`. I have disabled my Amazon CloudFront cache during this configuration temporarily to ensure that’s not a factor.

Comment: Open the cert in the browser and view the details. It is saying that *.example.com is not in the list of domain names in the certificate.

Comment: What do you mean by “open the cert in the browser”?

Comment: https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-to-view-ssl-certificate-details-in-every-browser

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- Go to AWS S3 and create a new bucket.
- Name it my desired subdomain (`d.example.com`).
- Make it public.
- Enable static web hosting.
- Set hosting type to Redirect.
- Set host name to desired redirect URL (`discourse.example.com`).
- Note its static website hosting bucket website endpoint for later (looks like `http://d.example.com.s3-website.aws-region-2.amazonaws.com`).
- Go to CloudFront and create a new distribution.
- Paste the noted endpoint into the origin domain (**do not choose the similar but slightly different option from the dropdown**).
- Add alternate/CNAME as desired new subdomain (`d.example.com`).
- Choose existing AWS certificate for SSL.
- Go to Route 53, choose the existing hosted zone, and create a new record.
- Leave type as A record.
- Set record name to desired subdomain (`d`).
- Change value to Alias.
- Route traffic to CloudFront.
- Choose the new distribution from the dropdown.
- Wait a few minutes before attempting to load the new subdomain in the browser.